# How to show $\lvert e^{i2t\sin\theta}\rvert= e^{-2\Im(t\sin(\theta))}$

Tags: complex-analysis

First, I say sorry if this might looks obvious for you. I just confused since I can't found something related about this.

Here's the problem :
[image]

All I know about modulus is
$$\lvert x+iy\rvert = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$. And even if I apply this on
$\lvert e^{i2t\sin\theta}\rvert$, this gives me $1$ as the result.

So, where does $\Im(t\sin(\theta))$ come from? Please explain the step with detail. Thanks. Your little help means a lot to me. Thanks in advance.

And btw, $t>0, t\in \Bbb R$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $t$ is any real number then indeed $|e^{it}|=1$, you are right. It follows that if $z=x+iy$ is a complex number then:

$|e^{iz}|=|e^{i(x+iy)}|=|e^{ix}e^{-y}|=e^{-y}=e^{-Im(z)}$

Now, when you checked the result in Wolfram you obviously didn't write that $2t\sin(\theta)$ is a real number, so you got an answer in the general case, where it might be any complex number. After all, if $2t\sin(\theta)$ is real then its imaginary part equals $0$, so the answer still remains the same.